# Con respecto a la sentencia "compareTo"

Tags: java, netbeans, xcode, if, comparaciones

Tengo una duda en cuanto a la sentencia **compareTo**.

Si yo tengo:

```
if(x.compareTo(y)==0)
```

Entiendo que estoy preguntando si el valor de **x** es igual al de **y**. ¿Pero si quiero preguntar si son distintos? ¿Debo colocar una negación adelante?

```
if(!(x.compareTo(y)==0))
```

No entiendo cómo formular esa pregunta.

Lo segundo que me causa ruido es cuando quiero preguntar si **x** es mayor o igual a **y**. ¿Debo escribirlo como:

```
if(x.compareTo(y)>0 && x.compareTo(y)==0)
```

O hay una forma más resumida?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

El compareTo devuelve 3 posibles resultado 1, 0 y -1. Para los casos que das de ejemplo retornaria 1 si 'x' es mayor a 'y', retornaria 0 si 'x' es igual a 'y' y retornaria -1 si 'x' es menor a 'y'.
Entonces para saber si 'x' es mayor o igual a 'y' deberias preguntar:

```
if (x.compareTo(y) >= 0) { ... }
```

Comment: Ah muchas gracias! 
Y si son diferentes es como yo he puesto? O debo utilizar el mayor y menor?

Comment: Si, o también podés hacerlo así:

`if (x.compareTo(y) != 0) { ... }`

Comment: Gracias, ahora me sacaste las dudas :)